# mongoid/ mongodb query with time condition is extremely slow

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I want to select all the data which ts(**timestamp**) less than **specific time**

```
last_record = History.where(report_type: /#{params["report_type"]}/).order_by(ts: 1).only(:ts).last
History.where(:ts.lte => last_record.ts)
```

It seems this query will take super long time

I don't understand why, is there any quick way to do the sort of query ?

```
class History
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
  field :report_type, type: String
  field :symbol, type: String
  field :ts, type: Time
end
```

[image]

### The query log in console

```
Started GET "/q/com_disagg/last" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-10 10:36:55 +0800
Processing by QueryController#last as HTML
  Parameters: {"report_type"=>"com_disagg"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=admin command={:ismaster=>1} runtime: 0.4290ms
    ...  
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 GET_MORE     database=cot_development collection=histories limit=0 cursor_id=44966970901 runtime: 349.9560ms
```

#### Have set the timestamp as index, but still extremely slow query

> db.system.indexes.find()

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "ts" : 1 }, 
"name" : "ts_index",
 "ns" : "cot_development.histories" }
```

Comment: Maybe there is no index for ts?

Comment: Yes, there is no index for `ts` I will add it later, but it should not be slow that way

Comment: Is Time.now a function? returning the time (for every comparison). This could slow down things too (maybe make a copy of the value or use a constant number to test).

Comment: @Matthias please see my updates

Comment: You need an index on `ts`; otherwise, your query scans the whole collection every time.

Comment: @wdberkeley Hi still query for a long long time. please see my updates

Comment: Post an explain for the query.